# Javascript soap form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, web-services

I want form value to be replace with xml value while submit and match the user and pass for login  ..

XML Data hosted

[in place of GlobalID i have user and  languageid i have pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em2ch.png)

Form Body :-

```
<input type="text" value="username" placeholder="enter user name"><br>
    <input type="password" value="password" placeholder="enter password"><br>
    <input type="text" value="macid" placeholder="Mac ID"><br>
    <input type="text" value="version" placeholder="Version"><br>

    <button class="actionSubmit" onclick="loginValidation()" type="submit">Login      </button>
```

Help me to fix this. i need to do with js or jquery